# Read Uncommited SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, transactions, azure-sql-database

I am running following SQL statement on SQL Azure database:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;  
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

UPDATE Project SET Name = 'NewLim2' WHERE Projectid = 403179
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Then during the 10 seconds delay I use another connection which performs following select:

```
SELECT * FROM Project WHERE Projectid = 403179
```

But its result is 'NewLim' as Name (original value) and 'NewLim2' is after the committing. When I run transaction with Read uncommitted I suppose that it will read updated value even before commit. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to reconsider what you are doing here. That isolation level is the same thing as splattering nolock on every query. It can and will cause some major problems. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: yeah, I know about that. We tried to achieve that data written by the transaction can be read by any other process and using a transaction is only because that if some part fails it gets entirely rollbacked. Is there any other option how to rollback e.g. 3-4 DML statements (and make others see already written data) without using a transaction?

Comment: The query that is reading the table would need to be using read uncommitted to see those changes.

Comment: yes, but I need another approach. something like; create transaction; create records; commit or rollback - but created records need to be visible immediately and transaction is there only because of possible rollback to revert it all. I am wondering about using C# TransactionScope but I suppose it also creates native SQL transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

before your Select statement.

Comment: you're right, it works. I was always in that setting it on connection that is doing the transaction is enough. so there's no way how to make data 'visible' only by setting isolation level at the connection that is doing the data manipulation?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. But then, I'm not a DBA.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out,Isolation levels are only for select Statements,below statement you have in your update doesn't make any sense

**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;**

Reason why you didn't got uncommitted data was due not having required Isolation level in your select as mentioned in answer

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just make your query, ending by "WITH UR" like we can do in e.g. DB2?

So:

```
SELECT * FROM Project WHERE Projectid = 403179 WITH UR
```

Comment: No that doesn't mean anything in SQL Azure database

Comment: For asking clarification questions like this one, you need the commenting privilege, in order to avoid this to turn into a non-answer, which gets flagged and deleted. Please delete this post yourself. Take the [tour] and read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead to understand why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).